# Amount of Aggadeta in Talmud Bavli

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, agada-stories-legends

Was wondering whether anyone has seen a write-up of/knows off-hand the amount of daf of aggadeta in the Talmud Bavli (for argument's sake, let's take the Daf Yomi count of 2711.)
Thanks!

Comment: Grab the Maharsha and some OCR software; you'll see where the font changes for Aggadeta vs Halacha. Alternatively, take a Vilna Shas and look for spans without a Ner Mitzvah footnote pointing you to halachic sources. (Okay the latter isn't perfect, you can have a nine-daf debate in halacha without a clear conclusion, but still close.)

Comment: Oh, Ein Yaakov is on Sefaria?! Somebody scrape that and compare it to the full Shas. I'm not currently handy with their API, but sounds like a good coding assignment.

Comment: I defiantly saw estimates that are very high, like a fifth or so. (There are lots and lots of short aggadot that don't get into Ein Yaakov etc. and there are long stretches that take less than their share of daffim, like the beginning and end of berachos, perek chelek, and in megilah.)

Comment: Are you asking how many pages are entirely aggadeta? How many pages contain any aggadeta at all? How many pages it would be if you added up all the aggadeta? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

Ein Yaakov (Hebrew: עין יעקב‎) is a 16th Century compilation of all the Aggadic material in the Talmud together with commentaries. Its introduction contains an account of the history of Talmudic censorship and the term Gemara. It was compiled by Jacob ibn Habib and (after his death) by his son Rabbi Levi ibn Habib. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Yaakov))

You can find the Ein Yaakov text on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Ein_Yaakov?lang=bi).
The way it's broken up on Sefaria, there seems to be about 350 chapters.

Comment: Not going to downvote this because thanks for the link, but I'm kinda looking for daf amount...

Comment: Well, I'm upvoting it! I had no idea how even to look for an answer; Yaakov David used his head and made some progress.