# Agadah / Talmud Bavli Map

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, agada-stories-legends

Is there a spreadsheet or list available, linking the אגדתא of shas with the standard pagination? I.e., flagging daf כ ע"א, כב ע"ב, כה ע"א as having אגדתא. (Anything in עין יעקב, but in a single spreadsheet without the text.)

Related: [Amount of Aggadeta in Talmud Bavli](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118635/amount-of-aggadeta-in-talmud-bavli)

Comment: If you find one let me know

Comment: The ein yaakov is a collection of just the אגדתא - it isn't a spreadsheet, but perhaps you could use that